# Optimization of multiple aggregate sorting in SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, spree

I have a postgres query written for the Spree Commerce store that sorts all of it's products in the following order: In stock (then first available), Backorder (then first available), Sold out (then first available).

In order to chain it with rails scopes I had to put it in the order by clause as opposed to anywhere else. The query itself works, and is fairly performant, but complex. I was curious if anyone with a bit more knowledge could discuss a better way to do it? I'm interested in performance, but also different ways to approach the problem.

```
 ORDER BY (
    SELECT 
      CASE 
      WHEN tt.count_on_hand > 0 
      THEN 2
      WHEN zz.backorderable = true
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0 
      END
    FROM (
      SELECT
        row_number() OVER (dpartition),
        z.id,
        bool_or(backorderable) OVER (dpartition) as backorderable
      FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (spree_variants.id) spree_products.id, spree_stock_items.backorderable as backorderable
        FROM spree_products
        JOIN "spree_variants" ON "spree_variants"."product_id" = "spree_products"."id" AND "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
        JOIN "spree_stock_items" ON "spree_stock_items"."variant_id" = "spree_variants"."id" AND "spree_stock_items"."deleted_at" IS NULL
        JOIN "spree_stock_locations" ON spree_stock_locations.id=spree_stock_items.stock_location_id
        WHERE spree_stock_locations.active = true
      ) z window dpartition as (PARTITION by id)
    ) zz 
    JOIN (
      SELECT
        row_number() OVER (dpartition),
        t.id,
        sum(count_on_hand) OVER (dpartition) as count_on_hand
      FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT ON (spree_variants.id) spree_products.id, spree_stock_items.count_on_hand as count_on_hand
        FROM spree_products
        JOIN "spree_variants" ON "spree_variants"."product_id" = "spree_products"."id" AND "spree_variants"."deleted_at" IS NULL 
        JOIN "spree_stock_items" ON "spree_stock_items"."variant_id" = "spree_variants"."id" AND "spree_stock_items"."deleted_at" IS NULL
      ) t window dpartition as (PARTITION by id)
    ) tt ON tt.row_number = 1 AND tt.id = spree_products.id
    WHERE zz.row_number = 1 AND zz.id=spree_products.id
  ) DESC, available_on DESC
```

The `FROM` shown above determines whether or not a product is backorderable, and the `JOIN` shown above determines the stock in inventory. Note that these are very similar queries, except that I need to determine if something is backorderable based on a locations ability to support backorders and its state, `WHERE spree_stock_locations.active=true`.

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: I would suspect that much of the logic is already in the main query.  That is just a guess, because you have only shown the `order by` clause.

Comment: The main query is a simple data query, the order by contains all of the logic I described. In order to make it a Ruby on Rails scope, it needed to be this way. It's not ideal, but it works.

Comment: . . I would suggest that you move any uncorrelated subqueries into a common table expression (`with` clause).

Comment: Great, thanks Gordon!